# How to implement Quick Fix / Quick Assist for custom eclipse editor?

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-pde, eclipse-plugin

I have extended `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor` to implement a custom editor.
For this editor, I have defined a marker type (`org.eclipse.core.resources.markers` extension point) and an annotation type (`org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes` extension point) to mark specific parts of code in my editor. I use a reconciler to update my annotation model.

Now I want to add a quick fix / quick assist feature. I simply want eclipse, to show a box with proposals, when I hover over an annotated part of the code and replace that part with a given string, when I click on a proposal. Just like the quick fix feature for the java editor.

So, what is the best way to implement this behavior?

I read about marker resolution generators and quick assist processors, but I'm still confused how it all works together...

I would be glad, if someone could point me to the right direction.

**EDIT:** From what I've understood so far, a `MarkerResolutionGenerator` is responsible for showing quick fixes in the problems view. To get quick fixes in the source viewer, I would have to set a `QuickAssistAssistant` for my `SourceViewer` and implement a `QuickAssistProcessor` which returns `CompletionProposals`.
Is this the right way to do it?

**EDIT2:** I'm wondering if I need `Markers` at all, or only `Annotations`, I'm confused...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found out how to get Quick Fix to work for my editor.

I use the `annotationTypes` extension point to register my own annotation type and the `markerAnnotationSpecification` extension point to specify the look and feel. In my custom `SourceViewerConfiguration` class I override `getAnnotationHover(...)` to return a `DefaultAnnotationHover` object and `getTextHover(...)` to return a `DefaultTextHover` object, so the annotations are shown in my source viewer.

Then I override `getReconciler(...)` to return a `MonoReconciler` with my own implementation of `IReconcilingStrategy` to create the annotations in its `reconcile(...)` method. And finally I override `getQuickAssistAssistant(...)` to return a `QuickAssistAssistant` with my own implementation of `IQuickAssistProcessor`. The `computeQuickAssistProposals(...)` method in the processor class computes the quick fix proposals which show up, when I press CTRL+1.

I don't create any `Marker` objects and don't use a `MarkerResolutionGenerator`, since the marker concept is much more heavyweight than using only annotations and the functionality which annotations provide fits my needs.

Answer (score 3):

You have to register an extension to the extension point org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution. This extension refers to a markerType (using the markerId), and also a resolution generator.

The latter component is responsible for calculating the possible fixes: it reads the marker, it can check the related files, etc., and creates marker resolution instances. These resolution instances basically process the erroneous files, and hopefully fix the original problem.

During marker resolution, you should not worry about removing the markers, as after the fix is executed, sometimes the validation would run again (e.g. during the build, or if no automatic validation is available, then manually - but it is not the task of the marker resolution to update the list of markers).

Comment: I did so, but the methods of my marker resolution generator are never invoked. I think this is the right way, if you have a Builder which manages markers on save and build, but I add Annotations to my AnnotationModel, because I just need error marking while typing.
Or do I have to set something in my SourceViewerConfiguration to get the resolution generator to work?

Comment: AFAIK Quick fixes are not registered to annotations but to markers. You can automatically create annotations from markers using the markerannotationspecification extension point.

Comment: I'm now creating markers and adding MarkerAnnotations to my annotation model, but the quick fix is only available in the problems view. How do I get the quick fix to appear on mouse over in the source viewer?

Comment: I'm sorry- I don't have any further ideas... Maybe if I will have time, I will try to look for more documentation/source code...