# How do I show quick fixes when I hover over an error in my custom editor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I've written an eclipse editor for my own DSL. When an editor is opened or saved I check the contents and create problem markers for any syntax errors. The markers show up in my editor as expected, and also in the Problems view.

I've got an extension point `org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution` and provide an implementation of `IMarkerResolutionGenerator` which creates resolutions for problem markers. This works fine; when I right click a problem in the Problems view the Quick Fix option shows in the context menu and works fine.

My editor extends `SourceViewerConfiguration` and I override `getQuickAssistAssistant()`, returning an extension of `QuickAssistAssistant`. This allows me to right click a problem in the editor and see the Quick Fix option in the menu.

I'd really like to get the quick fix resolutions to appear when I hover over the problem in the editor, just like in the java editor. Currently just the problem text appears in the tooltip. Is there a seperate hook into this or should it be covered in two quick fix hooks I've already implemented?

Comment: Assuming you actually have an `TextSourceViewerConfiguration`, have a look at `TextSourceViewerConfiguration.getTextHover(ISourceViewer, String)`...

Comment: @TonnyMadsen - You assume correctly, and I override `getTextHover`. Might have a look at `ITextHoverExtension` and `ITextHoverExtension2` though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a solution for myself: [How to implement Quick Fix / Quick Assist for custom eclipse editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945371/how-to-implement-quick-fix-quick-assist-for-custom-eclipse-editor/8999952#8999952)

From what I've understood, Markers show up in the Problems View and Annotations show up in the editor (on the ruler and on mouse hover).

I use the `org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes` extension point to register my own annotation type and the `org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification` extension point to specify the look and feel. In my custom `SourceViewerConfiguration` class I override `getAnnotationHover(...)` to return a `DefaultAnnotationHover` object and `getTextHover(...)` to return a `DefaultTextHover` object, so the annotations are shown in my source viewer.

To create annotations, you could use `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.SimpleMarkerAnnotation`, you can construct a `SimpleMarkerAnnotation` passing a marker object to the constructor.
Then you need to add the annotation to the annotation model. You can use `getAnnotationModel()` on your `SourceViewer` and then `addAnnotation(Annotation annotation, Position position)` on the `AnnotationModel`. All annotations in the model will be shown in the editor.

You could also use `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractMarkerAnnotationModel` as your annotation model. Then you won't need to create annotation objects first, since `AbstractMarkerAnnotationModel` provides a method `addMarkerAnnotation(IMarker marker)`.

Have a look at the [`IAnnotationModel` interface](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ftext%2Fsource%2FIAnnotationModel.html).